# PHP strings not concatenating

Tags: php

I'm reading a file in PHP line by line by using a custom line delimeter, but i'm having difficulty concatenating the line character back onto the string after.

```
$newhtml = "";
if ($handle) {
          while (($line = stream_get_line($handle, 4096, "</br>")) !== false) 
          {
            $newhtml = "{$line}{$newhtml}" . "</br>";
          }
          echo $newhtml;
          fclose($handle);
```

I'd be expecting each line of the file to come out on different lines, but the  tag isn't even being shown in the dev console.

Comment: `$newhtml = "{$line}{$newhtml}" . "</br>";` should be `$newhtml .= "{$line}{$newhtml}" . "</br>";` Notice the dot before the equals.

Comment: That's not the case.  since he includes `$newhtml` in his assignment, the `.=` is not necessary.

Comment: `</br>` is invalid html.  Though I'm not sure if that has anything to do with your issue.  perhaps you could include some sample input and output and what your expected output is.

Answer (score 0):

Actually with your existing block of code below

```
while (($line = stream_get_line($handle, 4096, "</br>")) !== false) {
    $newhtml = "{$line}{$newhtml}" . "</br>"; // problem happening here with = 
}
```

You're overwriting the `$newhtml` value with every while loop iteration.So, you'll get only the last value after the iteration ends. As I understand your requirement, you want to concatenate every line to the `$newhtml` variable. To do so just modify this like

```
$newhtml = "{$line}{$newhtml}" . "</br>";
```

to

```
$newhtml.= $line."</br>"; // with dot before =
```

**Look an extra dot(`.`) before the equal sign and remove the unnecessary usage of {$newhtml} variable again**

Comment: Since `$newhtml` is included in the assignment, using `.=` as well will duplicate all the lines multiple times.

Comment: @LeeBlake agreed, I didn't see that mate. Thanks for pointing me out. I've **Edited** my answer. Please have a look again.

Comment: That still might not answer the OP's question, though to be honest it is somewhat vague.  `$newhtml = "{$newhtml}{$line}" . "</br>";` would also do the same thing as your changes (switching the order of `$line` and `$newhtml`.  However, the OP seems to be claiming that the `</br>` is not being included somehow.  I could be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

From the code you given I can guess that you want to put last line as first, you can use array for this:

```php
<?php
if ($handle) {
    $lines = [];
    while (($line = stream_get_line($handle, 4096, "</br>")) !== false) 
    {
        $lines[] = $line;
    }
    $reversed = array_reverse($lines);
    echo join('<br>' $reversed);
    fclose($handle);
}
```

But if you just want to display lines as they are in the files, just simplify the code:

```php
<?php
if ($handle) {
    $lines = [];
    while (($line = stream_get_line($handle, 4096, "</br>")) !== false) 
    {
        echo $line . '<br>';
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
```